# Is there a way to determine which coordinate (x,y) belongs to TOP RIGHT corner of the polygon?

Tags: algorithm, polygon

Supposing that I have an array of coordinates (x and y) in random order,
I need to determine which particular coordinates belong to Top Right corner.

e.g. :
arr = [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4]
Now is there any way to determine which x and y coordinates will be of the Top Right Corner.

Comment: What is the top right corner of [this polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDYJl.png)?

Comment: Is your "polygon" guaranteed to be an axis-aligned rectangle? In that case you should probably use the specific term "axis-aligned rectangle" instead of the very vague "polygon".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the top-right box having top-left and bottom-right coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002491/how-can-i-get-the-top-right-box-having-top-left-and-bottom-right-coordinates)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Question asks if there is a way to determine top right corner of the polygon. Answer depends on the definition of **top right corner**. How do you define it? 
If it is defined as the rightmost point, then we know that maximum `x` among all the `x` coordinates will be at the top right corner. But cannot make any assumption on the `y` coordinate. 
If it is defined as the highest point, then we know what `y` should be but do not know anything about `x`. 
If you define it to be the both rightmost and highest point, then `(x, y)` should consist of the highest `x` and `y` values among all the coordinates. However, with this definition you acknowledge that **top right corner** doesn't necessarily exist.